# Adding a Newly Created Object to a Vector

Tags: object, pointers, vector

I recently stated using pointers in a program and when I try the following, I am given this error.

```
stored_points.push_back(new Point(anchor_y,anchor_x,last_direction));
```

error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Point *' to 'Point &&' with[
              _Ty=Point
         ]
         Reason: cannot convert from 'Point *' to 'Point'
         No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I understand that using new gives a pointer back and that .push_back can't accept that, however, I have no idea on how to go about fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you defining your vector?
If its `vector<Point>`, try changing it to `vector<Point*>`. This tells the vector to store pointers to the objects instead.

Comment: When doing that, a plethora of other errors come into existence, is there anything else I need to do to account for this?

Comment: For the same line, i'm receiving the same error and with this line     "if(*stored_points.at(index).x==index_x_p&&*stored_points.at(index).y==index_y_p){" i'm getting "error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union 
1>          type is 'Point *'
1>          did you intend to use '->' instead?"  My next response will be in over eleven hours, sorry for the delay in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to dereference the pointer to the `Point` at `index`, but the compiler is interpreting it as a dereference to `stored_points`. Putting parenthesis like `*(stored_points.at(index)).x` (same for `y`) should fix it. However, you don't need to access the member like that, as C++ provides a shorthand way to do it; instead use `stored_points.at(index)->x`. The `->` is basically the pointer version of the `.` accessor.

Comment: I did try that earlier and this error appeared.    error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'int' to 'int *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\asher\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\icemaze\icemaze\icemaze.cpp(2126): error C2040: '==' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Comment: Could you post some more code? Like, what type is `index_x_p` and the `x` member of your `Point` class? It sounds like one of them is a pointer, and the other one is a plain `int`.

Comment: Here is the constructor:                                                     x = new int;
  y = new int;
  dt_next_point = new char;
  dt_last_point = new char;
  *x = b;
  *y = a;
  *dt_next_point= NULL;
  *dt_last_point=last;    index_x_p is indeed an int.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using an `int` pointer as your `x` and `y` member, instead of just a normal `int`? Usually there's no reason to just have a basic type pointer created as `new int`. Pointers to basic types are usually for arrays or storing the address of another variable, not for creating an object-like variable. Changing your code to `*(stored_points.at(index)->x)` should fix it, but a better fix would be to change your `x` and `y` members to `int`s, and change your constructor to `x = 0; y = 0;` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick work-around would be change the definition of your vector. Instead of `vector<Point>`, change it to `vector<Point *`>.

But you should seriously consider using smart pointer in such situation. So `vector<shared_ptr<Point> >` is what you may want to consider.

Smart pointer is available in Boost and TR1.